# How to inject Spring DAO class in QuartzJobBean, using JobDetailFactoryBean Annotated way

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-4

How to inject Spring DAO class in QuartzJobBean, I am using JobDetailFactoryBean instantiated at Config class level. I am using Spring4 Quartz 2.2.1 Annotation ways

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(SchedulerService.class);

        //Should I inject DAO here?

        factory.setGroup("mygroup");
        factory.setName("myjob");
        return factory;
    }
}
```

QuartzJobBean been extended to execute

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@Service
public class SchedulerService extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Autowire
    public SchedulerDAO schDAO;

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("---SchedulerService .executeInternal ----");

        try {
            init(ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap(), 
            ctx.getScheduler().getContext());
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // I want to do DAO methods used here - how to do that? 
        // Can get access to DAO
        schDAO.getSomeMethods();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Quartz, does not know anything about your configuration class, so it can't autowired an unknown bean.
Go to SchedulerConfig.java and declare your service or DAO as autowired, then use a jobdata and map this object in order to be passed in Quartz. Then you can use it inside executeInternal method of Quartz.
For example

```
@Configuration 
public class mplampla{ 
@Autowired
private YourDAO dao;
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
    JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("YourDAO", dao);
    factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
    return factory;
}
}
```

Then in your YourJob.java

```
public class YourJob extends QuartzJobBean {
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap dataMap = ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    YourDAO dao = (YourDAO) dataMap.get("YourDAO");
    dao.getMethods();
}
}
```

Be carefull if you are using @Service class and YourDAO class as @Transational, you will get error about undeclared Bean. In this case you have to pass the inteface of your DAO.